# multi field widget - format in symfony backend

Tags: symfony1, widget, backend

How to format fields of multifield widget (widget with many inputs) in backed module? I have widget based on sfWidgetFormSchema and in backend all fields of this widget are displayed in one line (in the same div). How to display them properly? It is possible in generator.yml?

Answer (score 1):

How to do this right way.

1. Take a look at `sfWidgetFormDate` class as an example of multiinput widget. Write your own widget class.
2. Take an `sfValidatorDate` as an example of multiinput validator class. Write your own validator for your own widget.
3. Replace desired field's widget and validator to yours.
4. Enjoy your fancy new tricky form control.

Comment: No this widgets (sfWidgetFormDate, sfWidgetFormDateRange) don't have code which format structure of inputs. Date widget have all inputs in the same line.